# Poisson kernel approximates to the identity

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

The question comes from Shakarchi and Stien's real analysis p.111, he said that the Poisson kernel for the disc approximates to the identity without proof. However, I don't see that fact immediately, could anybody give me some ideas? Here is the definitions.

A kernel $K_\delta $ (assumed to be Lebesgue integrable and $\delta >0$) can approximate to the identity if it satisfyies:

1. $\int_{\mathbb R^d}K_\delta(x)dx=1$
2. $\left |K_\delta(x)\right |\le A\delta^{-d}$ for all $\delta>0$
3. $\left |K_\delta(x)\right |\le A\delta/|x|^{d+1}$ for all $\delta>0$ and $x\in \mathbb R^d$

The Poisson kernel is defined by

$$P_\delta(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac1{2\pi}\frac{1-(1-\delta)^2}{1-2(1-\delta)\cos x+(1-\delta)^2} &\text{if }|x|\le\pi\\
0 & \text{if } |x|>\pi
\end{cases}$$

Here we need $0<\delta<1$.

Comment: @Alex R.: Thanks for your advice. I can prove (1) now but still cannot prove (2) and (3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
   & 1 - 2(1-\delta)\cos 2x + (1-\delta)^{2} \\
   & = 1-2(1-\delta)\{1-2\sin^{2}x\}+(1-\delta)^{2} \\
   & = (1-(1-\delta))^{2}+4(1-\delta)\sin^{2}x \\
   & = \delta^{2}+4(1-\delta)\sin^{2}x
\end{align}
Therefore,
$$
           0 \le P_{\delta}(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{\delta(2-\delta)}{\delta^{2}+4(1-\delta)\sin^{2}x}.
$$
So, you have
$$
       P_{\delta}(x) \le \frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{2\delta}{\delta^{2}}=\frac{1}{\pi}\delta^{-1} \\
       P_{\delta}(x) \le \frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{2}{4(1-\delta)\sin^{2}x} \le \frac{1}{4\pi x^{2}},\;\;\delta\approx 0.
$$